# Explicitly allocate memory on stack or on heap

Tags: memory, memory-management, functional-programming

I'm seeking for a modern programming language that allows to specify where a variable of a given type, primitive or complex, will be allocated. C++ implements this behavior:

Stack

```
auto stackAllocatedVal = MyClass(params);
```

Heap

```
auto heapAllocatedPtr = new MyClass(params);
```

or

```
void* heapAllocatedSpacePtr = malloc(SIZE);
//now we can fill the allocated space on heap
```

The languages capable of this ,which I know, are c++ and Rust. But I seek for a more functional one. Any advices ?

Comment: What does it means “more functional”?

Comment: @Renzo functional as a programming paradigm

Comment: C++ provides lambda expressions, so you could use it in a functional programming style.

Comment: @Renzo Thats too little. After programming in scala, I would really miss its functional features

Comment: Why? Why do you need to be able to *specify* that as a *user* of the language? That being said, OCaml does at least let you declare references (pointers).

Comment: @JaredSmith To write more efficient code. As a high level language like scala adds memory overhead when accessing raw data like huge array of floats. That heavily increases my timings. I write a basic voxel engine in c++ and scala. Code that manages raw data in scala is 2 times slower than c++. Not to mention overall slowness of JVM

Comment: @Rulli no I totally get that, its how manipulating (and probably mutating) a huge array of floats relates to a 'functional' paradigm that is confusing me. What specific features of Scala are you missing in the lower level languages? Rich user types? `map`, `flatMap`, etc? If you're talking about zero cost abstractions, then yeah, c++, Rust, Nim, not many options.

Comment: If you do not add more details (for instance, to be more precise on the characteristics of the language: immutable data? high order functions? etc.) and possibly a concrete example, I think the question is too generic for StackOverflow and will be closed.

Comment: @Renzo I'l just go with Rust. Not many options anyway

Answer (score 0):

[MLKit with regions](http://www.elsman.com/mlkit/) implements a functional programming language [Standard ML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) extended with region-based memory management, which may be close to what you are looking for.  In general, the main technical challenge here is to guarantee safety under manual memory management, for instance when an object X is deallocated *before* another object which points to X.